# Можно ли добавить событие клика форме Visual Studio 13 c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, события, click

Нужно чтоб при клике в рабочей области приложения (Form1) создавалась кнопка в текущих координатах указателя мыши. Возможно ли такое осуществить и как это сделать?

Нужно добавлять событие программно, после нажатия определенной кнопки!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подпишитесь на событие `Form.MouseClick` или переопределите метод `OnMouseClick`.
Пример переопределения:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        Button btn = new Button
        {
            Location = e.Location, // e.Location - координаты мыши
            Visible = true,
            Text = "Some text"
        };
        Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

Либо событие. Подписываетесь на него где-либо в форме:

```
MouseClick += MyForm_MouseClick;
```

Сам обработчик:

```
private void MyForm_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = new Button
    {
        Location = e.Location, // e.Location - координаты мыши
        Visible = true,
        Text = "Some text"
    };
    Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: Обалдеть это работает, еще б понять как, но это я уже сам, большое спасибо!

Comment: Как сделать сохранение кнопок на форме, чтоб при следующем ее запуске они остались в прежнем состоянии?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Это совершенно другой вопрос. Я бы рекомендовал при создании кнопок сохранять в файл (или в `Settings`) все пары координат, чтобы при следующем старте программы прочитать их и воссоздать кнопки в этих местах.

Comment: @Vyacheslav вполне тянет на самостоятельный вопрос, правда боюсь вариантов решений может быть слишком много и, скорее всего, ни одного "истинно" правильного =)