# Как задизейблить кнопки в форме VS2015

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется форма на *WinForms*. На форме есть кнопочки. Для них написана процедура их отключения. Можно ли включить их обратно после введения данных в определённый `TextBox`?

Comment: используйте событие для текстбокса к примеру KeyUp или LostFocus https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user2455111 если добавить пример кода, получится отличный ответ. Может, опубликуете?

Comment: не вижу смысла, вопрос тривиальный и на раз находится в гугле. Проголосую пожалуй за удаление вопроса

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли добавить событие клика форме Visual Studio 13 c#?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486319/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b5-visual-studio-13-c)

Comment: @user2455111 [Вопрос всегда тривиальный, после того как нашел решение!](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/616/6)

Answer (score 0):

> Можно ли включить их обратно после введения данных в определённый
>   TextBox

В вашем вопросе выражение "после введения данных" означает привязку на какое-то событие во времени. Как например, выйти на перемену после звонка или уйти после уроков. Для этого в языке c# предусмотрены [события](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/awbftdfh.aspx). Как правило подобного рода задачи решаются с помощью них. Обычно в Win forms у каждого элемента управления есть свой необходимый набор событий. В вашем случае для `TextBox` существуют такие события как KeyUp (которое срабатывает в тот момент, когда вы отпускаете клавишу на клавиатуре) и LostFocus (срабатывает, если текущий элемент управления потерял фокус). Список событий для `TextBox`  можно увидеть [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx).
Для того, чтобы подписаться на событие вам нужно в дизайнере у вашего контрола зайти в окно `Properties` нажать на кнопку событий и щелкнуть 2 раза ЛКМ на необходимом вам событии. Будет добавлен примерно следующий код:

```
private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}
```

в котором мы можете написать что-то вроде:

```
private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   myButton.Enabled = false;
}
```

для установки свойства Enable, отключающего кнопку

PS: так же можете почитать про [делегаты](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173171.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

```
if(название_текстбокса.Text.Lenght!=0)
 название_кнопки.Enabled=true;
```

Если текстбокс не пустой, тогда вкл кнопку

Comment: Код без комментариев не очень-то понятен. А ещё у вас в нём опечатка была )